# C# WPF MultiClient One Database (App for private messaging and tasks)

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, messaging

I am experiencing a bit of a problem, not implemented one yet.
I'm building an application to be run on a private closed computer network, which contains multiple computers. This app should handle messages between AD(active directory) users and task issued to those users.

***Following is short description of some computers(each has WS2012R2 installed):***

**Gateway** - NAT router, users login to AccessPC1 and AccessPC2 with specific port defined in routing  with RDP thanks to this computer, the only one with direct access to Internet

**ActiveDirectory** - works as AD DS, DHCP, DNS

**AccessPC1** - computer where only users from AD group Group1 can remotely log in

**AccessPC2** - computer where only users from AD group Group2 can remotely log in

**SQLServer** - MSSQL 2014

What I need is to build a WPF app for that messaging and task management. Not gonna go deep in why all of it but my problem is I cannot determine what is the best way to build this app.

Well as always I want to keep it simple to create, so my first thoughts were simple WPF app with Entity framework but I fear that's not gonna work: *multiple EF threads/contexts on one DB, that smells to me like a huge no go.*

So my second idea was to create a network service(WCF REST) that's gonna be running on one pc(SQLServer for example) and every WPF client will be manipulating data trough there. That would mean that possible conflicts will be resolved in there and only one EF context will be running on one DB.

But there it comes. A bit of an overhead I fear, a lot more coding so I thought, my experiences are not that huge as many of you, is there anything easier that came to your minds? Any help is appreciated.

Looking forward for any of your ideas and help.

Comment: Multiple instances of `DbContext` is no problem at all. Servers would otherwise only be able to process the requests from one user at a time

Comment: Thx @AlexanderDerck, so do you recommend to just use client WPF with EF connected to DB? Keep in mind that each user will be running his own app/process and will be connecting to the same DB at the same time.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34441744/3410196